# Hibernate Envers for Doctrine?

Tags: hibernate, doctrine-orm, hibernate-envers, auditing

Doctrine 1.x and 2 both offer some kind of Versionable support in the form of a separate auditing table that tracks changes over time. However, the versions appear to be intended for per-row use (ie, they all maintain their own version number) instead of database-wide, such as in Hibernate Envers, which gives every row a unique revision number.

Does Doctrine actually provide support for that kind of behavior? I couldn't find anything online to suggest that it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No doctrine does not support such a behaviour. All you have is the AuditLog-Flag:

```
  actAs:
    Versionable:
      versionColumn: version
      className: %CLASS%Version
      auditLog: true
```

That activates a complete log of a row based change log. But the is nothing like a  table or database wide version.