# How to create custom field when using hibernate anvers

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, auditing, change-tracking

I'm starting a new project using spring 3.1, hibernate 4 and there is a requirement to track any activity on the application. activity tracking example `who changed what?` `from what to what?` and `at which time?` i've read an introductory tutorial on hibernate anvers. and to me it seems is more of data history than activity tracking unless i didn't get it at all.

is there a way to add custom field to that *_aud table to insert more user defined table. like `date_created`, `last_modified`, `created_by`, `updated_by` with its own `databefore` and `dataafter` kinda of fields.so basically i would like to add `createdby` , `updatedby` to anvers created table

Is there any way to do that. if yes, please point me to the right resource.

Thanks for reading .

Comment: Would [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963383/hibernate-envers-for-doctrine) be relevant?

Comment: not really, am on hibernate side trying to figure out whether it has somethings i've used in doctrine.

Answer (score 2):

In Envers each "production" table has a corresponding *_AUD table that stores historical state of entities. There is also a global REVINFO (`org.hibernate.envers.DefaultRevisionEntity`) table which contains revision number, timestamp and custom, user defined columns. An example showing how to extend DefaultRevisionEntity can be found in documentation. Currently there is no possibility to customize *_AUD tables, however Envers should answer all question that you have asked.

1. who changed what? - Store user credentials in REVINFO table.
2. from what to what? - That is quite general question :). Try exploring `org.hibernate.envers.AuditReader` and `org.hibernate.envers.query.AuditQueryCreator`.
3. at which time? - Timestamp is stored in REVINFO table. This timestamp reflects time when user has commited his changes.